# ignore_ppc stopped working

Tags: debian, cpu-frequency

Many Dell laptops suffer from an overstrict bios policy of setting the max cpu frequency to the lowest level, when the bios judges that the battery or charger are not performing as they should.

I had been using

```
echo 1 > /sys/module/processor/parameters/ignore_ppc
echo -n 2900000 >  /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq
echo -n 2900000 >  /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq
echo -n 2900000 >  /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq
echo -n 2900000 >  /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq
```

to break out of cpu frequency stuck at a minimum after suspend/hibernate.

However, this stopped working after an update from Debian 10 to Debian bullseyse/sid:

```
# echo -n 2900000 >  /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq
# cat  /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq
800000
```

The solution that I have found so far is to reload the acpi_cpufreq module:

```
# rmmod acpi_cpufreq
# modprobe acpi_cpufreq
```

after executing

```
# echo -n 2900000 >  /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq
```

After the module reload it seems that scaling_max_freq contains the previously set value.

Comment: [1] Did you check which cpufreq driver you have before the update? Maybe it was pcc_cpufreq and not acpi_cpufreq? [2] Did you set ignore_ppc after the update as well? [3] After you reload the module, what value does it show? Is it 2900000? Does it show a different value if you echo a different number?

Comment: 1) No, but I had never heard of pcc_cpufreq before. A bit improbable that it was in my lsmod and I didn't notice it, but can't exclude it.
2) Yes, echo 1 > /sys/module/processor/parameters/ignore_ppc, is temporary so I need to rerun it anyway. I have also tried making it permanent by putting it into the kernel boot options.
3) This is a bit stochastic. Normally it remains at the value that I set before reloading the module, i.e. 2900000. I have experienced however that some times reloading the module alters the limit to 2900100, which is over the max speed, and my cpu heats ups like crazy.

Comment: From what I see Debian 10 has kernel 4.9 and Debian 11 has kernel 4.19. From what I know there was a bug around this area where some sysfs values couldn't be changed (we saw it for IRQ affinity). Do you get a permission denied message when trying to change scaling_max_freq? Did you try installing a newer kernel by any chance? Anything in dmesg after you run the write command?